# Download random GitHub repositories with Powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I want to sample random GitHub public repositories to download them one by one for statistical purposes. I tried with the following Powershell code:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$id = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 500
$jsonContent = Invoke-WebRequest "http://api.github.com/repositories?since=$id" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I do get a list of public repositories but I can't limit the amount of them.
I tried with `?page=1&per_page=1` but it didn't work. I just want to parse the `clone_url` to `git clone`.

Any ideas? Other solutions to download random repos from github are also welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. This should work:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$id = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 99
$jsonContent = Invoke-WebRequest "http://api.github.com/repositories?since=1" | ConvertFrom-Json

$gitUrl = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($jsonContent[$id].url) | ConvertFrom-Json |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty git_url

git clone $gitUrl
```

If you want to clone via ssh be sure to change `git_url` to `ssh_url`.

### Explanation

The call to http://api.github.com/repositories?since=x allways represents the same last 100 repos so there is no need to randomize the number there.

The list from the first call gives you the api URL to a 100 Repos. So randomly check one of them and grep the url to clone from with another WebRequest to the api URL of the Repository.